# async/await - Getting error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncAction'"

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm currently trying to understand how the new keywords in c#5 is working with an example. I want send through a socket connection a message and catch the answar with a listener. Where i'm realy stuck is the point that i can't await a method, here is an example:

```
    private async void SubmitMessage(string strMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamSocket objSocket = new StreamSocket())
            {
                IAsyncAction objAction = await objSocket.ConnectAsync(new HostName(TargetHostname), TargetPortservice);
                objAction.Completed = delegate(IAsyncAction asyncAction, AsyncStatus asyncStatus)
                {
                    BindListener(objSocket.Information.LocalPort, objSocket, strMessage);
                };
            }
        }
        catch (Exception objException)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(objException.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Do anyone have an idea how to get this awaited? If i remove 'await' the syntax is correct. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Note your own `async` function should be of return type `Task`.  `await`ing an async function really awaits the implicitly-returned `Task`.  But since you're return type is `void`, if anyone `await`s on your funtion...crash.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `await`, you don't have to muck around with `IAsyncAction` at all, so something like this should work:

```
private async Task SubmitMessage(string strMessage)
{
    try
    {
        using (StreamSocket objSocket = new StreamSocket())
        {
            await objSocket.ConnectAsync(new HostName(TargetHostname), TargetPortservice);
            BindListener(objSocket.Information.LocalPort, objSocket, strMessage);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception objException)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(objException.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks. Yes but i need to call the BindListener Method then, when the connection is established, for that i assigned an anonymous method to 'objAction.Completed' but anyway it don't work.

Comment: if do that i get in Bindlistener the following error: `A method was called at an unexpected time` is the awaited method really done?

Comment: Yes; `await` will (asynchronously) wait for the `ConnectAsync` method to complete. By the time the socket is passed to `BindListener`, it has been connected.

Comment: You can't use `ConnectAsync` to establish a client socket and then use `BindListener` to establish a server socket. It's got to be either client *or* server. You may find my [.NET TCP/IP FAQ](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html) helpful.

Comment: @Stephan, thanks - yes you are right, so with the BindListener i'm starting 'a server' to sniff the local client port, which is opened with 'ConnectAsync'. Anyway the server will send me a feedback after i sent a message. Need to handle this :/

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about this but would this do?

```
IAsyncAction objAction = 
 objSocket.ConnectAsync(new HostName(TargetHostname), TargetPortservice);
await objAction;
//...
```

Comment: Hi spender, thanks thats right. But another question, how would you implement the completed handler with the await key? >> e.g. await objSocket.ConnectAsync(new HostName(TargetHostname), TargetPortservice).Compled(....>>>implementation of delegate<<<....)

Comment: @Riker, if you await the `IAsyncAction` then you don't need to register a callback for `Completed`... it's completed already... i.e. you're connected.

Comment: Hmm interesting, understand - ok, but if i call the `BindListener` after `await objAction` i get this error message: `<<A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E)>>   at Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener.BindServiceNameAsync(String localServiceName)
   at SamsungTV.App.Services.ConnectivityService.<BindListener>d__6.MoveNext()` It looks like that the BindListener is called before the awaited task is completed ???

Comment: @Riker, are you connecting to another machine or are you trying to open a listening socket to receive connections? You can't do both on the same socket.

Comment: yes i'm trying to connect to my samsung tv :) with a python sample it works fine. The listener is need to handle the answer if sent from tv

Comment: @Riker, you need to use a separate socket to listen with.

Comment: Hi spender thanks a lot, i had since yesterday a deeply look to the new c#5 async/await keywords. I freshed my konowledge about with a oreilly kindle book which spends the full book only special for this toppic. Currently i understand more and build my class from scratch new, now everything is different then this. Currently i have another problems but these are different than this here. Many thanks to you and to @Stephen